# Clojure, lein и запуск jar

Tags: jar, clojure

Делаю все как в примере https://github.com/daveray/seesaw но при запуске **lein run** выдает ошибку **No :main namespace specified in project.clj** . Добавил в проект  **:main hello.core** программка стала запускаться, но теперь при попытке выполнить **lein uberjar** появляется предупреждение:

---

Warning: The Main-Class specified does not exist within the jar. It may not be executable as expected. A gen-class directive may be missing in the namespace which contains the main method, or the namespace has not been AOT-compiled.

---

В итоге не получается запустить, ошибка **Error: Could not find or load main class hello.core**

---

project

```
(defproject hello "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write"
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
            [lein-try "0.4.1"]
            [seesaw "1.4.5"]]
:main hello.core
:aot :all)
```

---

core

```
(ns hello.core
(:use seesaw.core))

(defn -main [& args]
(invoke-later
(-> (frame :title "Hello",
       :content "Hello, Seesaw",
       :on-close :exit)
 pack!
 show!)))
```

Comment: какой полный путь к файлу **core.clj**?

Comment: scr\hello\core.clj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Всё верно, следуйте сообщению об ошибке.** Оно ведёт к решению.

`:main`-то вы указали... но как класса его для JVM действительно не существует, потому что он не объявлен и, следовательно, не скомпилирован (нельзя же скомпилировать то, чего нет).

У себя, при разработке, вы можете неявно (т. е. не зная этого) вызывать компилятор Clojure и говорить ему, что начать надо с указанного в `:main` пространства имён. Но при генерации jar `:main` должен представлять полноценную точку входа с точки зрения JVM. То бишь, класс со статическим методом `main`.

Как правило, это решается добавлением `:gen-class` в `ns`-форму нужного пространства имён:

```
(ns hello.core
    (:use seesaw.core)
    (:gen-class))
```

Так из пространства имён получится полноценный класс для JVM. В данном случае с одним методом `hello.core.main` (для JVM), представленным у вас `hello.core/-main` (в Clojure).

У вас уже есть в `project.clj` указание на `:aot :all` (компилировать заранее *всё*), поэтому вторая часть возможного решения в выведенном сообщении для вас неактуальна.

---

Подробнее по теме [на сайте Clojure](https://clojure.org/reference/compilation) и в ClojureDocs [про `ns`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns) и [про `gen-class`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/gen-class).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Я так понимаю, нужно всегда объявлять  (:gen-class) в классе с методом main?

Comment: @Hive всё, что планируется "светить наружу" в Java-экосистему. Точка входа в jar это один из случаев. В общем же случае нет, необязательно.